# Automatically update MySQL association table that has an auto increment foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I have an application where a particular event updates my database with `INSERT`s to two tables `A` and `B`. There is an additional association/link table `AB` with foreign keys `id_A`, `id_B` to `A` and `B` that maps their many-to-many relationship. My question is how to best update `AB` when one of the foreign keys isn't known to the application logic (in this case because it is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID).

Additional details:

- Only `id_B` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so its value is not known before the insert.
- `B` is updated with a multi-row `INSERT`; `A` is a single row `INSERT`.
- `id_B` is a unique key but there are possible duplicates which are handled by an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which replaces the old values with new ones.
- `A` and `B` are updated in the same transaction in response to the same event.
- MySQL 5.7 using InnoDB.

My idea was to include all the insert statements in a stored procedure where the final `INSERT` to `AB` would get the values for `id_B` from `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but apparently this will only return the value for the first row in a multi-row insert: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

I suppose a bonus would be if the logic to update `AB` could be separated out into a trigger or a different statement from what is being used to update the parent tables.

Edit: response to comments.

Comment: Will each record in A and each record in B always have at least one record in AB?

Comment: To be clear, you have three tables A, B and A_B, right?

Comment: BTW, two tables can't be inserted "at the same time" unless you use a single SQL INSERT statement (not likely). One will always occur before the other.

Comment: Also, is A's primary key also an autoincrement value?

Comment: @toonice 1) yes, 2) no. Updated Post to clarify.

Comment: @Sloan Yes. Updated post.

Comment: Provide some sample data to clarify the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Before the statement(s) used to insert your data into `A` and `B` place the following statement...

```
SET @before = ( SELECT MAX( id_B ) AS maxIDB
                FROM B );
```

This will find the largest value of `id_B` in `B` at this moment.  All subsequent insertions into `B` will have a larger value than this.  We can use this fact to our advantage.

After the above mentioned insert statement place the following statement...

```
INSERT INTO AB ( id_A,
                 id_B )
SELECT id_A_value,
       B.id_B
FROM B
WHERE B.id_B > @maxIDB;
```

Note : By your above question I am assuming that `id_A` is known.  I am representing this value with `id_A_value`.

This statement will insert into `AB` rows containing the known value of `id_A` and all of the freshly generated values of `id_B`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.